# C# Include a position in a list

Tags: c#, list, rank

I need to get a List of numbers, order and put a position on it (like a rank), have any better way than do a foreach?
I would prefer do it using LINQ, but didn't occour how to do it.

An example above of what I want:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var teste = new List<test>() {
                new test{ value = 3.4m }, new test{ value = 5.6m }, new test{ value = 1.2m }, new test{ value = 4.3m },
            };

            var posicao = 1;
            foreach (var item in teste.OrderBy(x => x.value))
            {
                item.position = posicao;
                posicao++;
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.position} / {item.value} #");
            }
        }
    }

    class test
    {
        public decimal value { get; set; }
        public decimal position { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't understand why you seek to store the position inside the object when it's known from the position of the object in the list? `foreach (var item in teste.OrderBy(x => x.value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{posicao++} / {item.value} #");
            }`

Comment: @CaiusJard Because the position desired is the position when sorted by value.

Comment: @NetMage how did the code in my comment not take that into account?

Comment: LINQ is for querying, not modifying. If you are willing to create a new `List` that is sorted (losing the original order) of new `test` objects (with the overhead that implies), then LINQ with two parameter `Select` is the way (and you could sort twice (!) to still preserve original order). Otherwise, your code is probably optimal.

Comment: @CaiusJard Your code still sorted, but your comment implied preserving original `List` order while knowing sorted position wasn't worthwhile. Imagine using `teste` in more than just a simple console output test scenario.

Comment: I'm still unsure it is; actually, if `position` is dependent on `value` then we already know position from the stored `value` with no need to sort by value, and then store the position, when we can just sort by value if we need the position, or pass round a sorted list? All in, a confusing question.

Comment: Also, if you don't mind the list being sorted, using `List.Sort` is probably better than `OrderBy` creating a new `List`.

Comment: @CaiusJard That would be in cases where the original order has some meaning - I wouldn't assume `test` is the actual class in use.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var a in teste.OrderBy(x => x.value)
    .Select((item, position) => (item, position)))
        Console.WriteLine($"{(a.position+1)} / {a.item.value} #");
```

Comment: Did you mean to `.OrderBy(x => x.value)` before you Select?

Comment: In more modern code you might want to use a tuple rather than an anonymous type here. Or use the pair type described in the question.

Comment: @EricLippert Is there a technical benefit to a tuple over the anonymous type?

Comment: @EricLippert `Tuple` as in `Item1 as object`, `Item2 as object`.. ? Or do you mean `ValueTuple`? (I've have thought `Tuple` was a bit of a step backwards over an anonymous type in that regard [of having named typed properties]?)

Comment: @BradleyUffner: Less collection pressure. And tuple types can be used across assemblies.

Comment: @EricLippert what does that mean?

Comment: @CaiusJard: I mean `(item, position)`. Tuples are first class in C# now.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich: You're going to have to be more specific in your question. What does what mean?

Comment: @EricLippert Sorry, referring to "Less collection pressure"

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich: The garbage collector observes many system behaviours when deciding when is the right time to perform a collection; we summarize some of those behaviours as "pressure"; that is, we take actions that pressure the GC into thinking that maybe it is a good time to do a collection. Many small heap allocations increase pressure because the GC thinks that there is probably a lot of garbage lying around. Anonymous types are reference types so they cause pressure; value types that are unboxed do not.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich: Collections are expensive, so if we can avoid causes of pressure like many heap allocations in a tight loop, we can get small performance wins that add up over time. There are a lot of subtle features in C# that you have probably never noticed that are designed to reduce pressure.

Comment: @ericlippert: thanks. My first read of "collection pressure" had me perplexed. I didn't realize you meant GC pressure. I thought you were referring to System.Collections. I hadn't thought of GC issues before when thinking anon types versus tuples

Comment: @EricLippert so you mean c#7's `System.ValueTuple<T1, T2..>` / `(test Item, int Position)`?

Comment: @CaiusJard: That's correct. I see this as an improvement over anonymous types, but your experience may be different!

Comment: @EricLippert Nono.. I get it now.. When you said "tuple" you meant in the dictionary* sense of the word, rather than the old `System.Tuple` - just had a minor panic for a moment there... :) *and not in the System.Collections.Generic sense of.. I'll go now

Comment: @EricLippert While I am all for efficiency improvements (and despair today's coding overheads), isn't this also the definition of premature optimization? (And I much prefer anonymous objects to `ValueTuple` for... reasons.)

Comment: @NetMage: Knuth was right that most optimizations are premature, but it is also the case that the performance environment is considerably more complex in modern code. Unnecessary collection pressure has real costs but it is difficult to measure because *the code which experiences the cost is typically not the code which created the pressure*. The C# and runtime teams work hard to ensure that pressure can be kept low most of the time without developers thinking about it too much, but I maintain that it is a good idea for everyone to keep the cost of a GC in mind.

Comment: @EricLippert Perhaps that implies a nice language enhancement - reduce the GC pressure caused by anonymous objects by creating the anonymous equivalent of `ValueTuple` with a public field/`struct` version.